# Trimming a datagridview duplicat rows except the recent one

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datagridview, duplicates

i'm in VS2008 Studio, i have this datagridview with multiple columns which the last column contains a date and time value.

lot's of rows are pretty the same except by they're date column.

what i wanted to do is to trim the whole datagridview duplicate rows except they're most recent ones based on they're date column.

i have sth like this:

Administrator,192.168.137.221,2,file://C:\WMPub\WMRoot\industrial.wmv , 07.Jul.2014 - 23:11:59

Administrator,192.168.137.221,2,file://C:\WMPub\WMRoot\industrial.wmv , 07.Jul.2014 - 
21:11:59

Administrator,192.168.137.221,2,file://C:\WMPub\WMRoot\industrial.wmv , 07.Jul.2014 - 22:11:59

Administrator,192.168.137.221,2,file://C:\WMPub\WMRoot\industrial.wmv , 07.Jul.2014 - 20:11:59

Administrator,192.168.137.221,2,file://C:\WMPub\WMRoot\industrial.wmv , 07.Jul.2014 - 11:11:59

Everyone   ,192.168.137.221,2,file://C:\WMPub\WMRoot\industrial.wmv , 07.Jul.2014 - 17:11:59

Everyone   ,192.168.137.221,2,file://C:\WMPub\WMRoot\industrial.wmv , 07.Jul.2014 - 14:11:59

the output i want should be like this:

**Administrator    192.168.137.221    2    file://C:\WMPub\WMRoot\industrial.wmv    07.Jul.2014 - 23:11:59 


Everyone   192.168.137.201    2    file://C:\WMPub\WMRoot\industrial.wmv    07.Jul.2014 - 17:11:59 


....**

please consider "," as column seprators! (i dont know how to draw a table here, sorry again)!
i have this snippet that trim the duplicate lines in a datagridview but it lacks preserving the latest entry:

```
Public Function RemoveDuplicateRows(ByVal dTable As DataTable, ByVal colName As String) As DataTable
        Dim hTable As New Hashtable()
        Dim duplicateList As New ArrayList()
        For Each dtRow As DataRow In dTable.Rows
            If hTable.Contains(dtRow(colName)) Then
                duplicateList.Add(dtRow)
            Else
                hTable.Add(dtRow(colName), String.Empty)
            End If
        Next

        For Each dtRow As DataRow In duplicateList
            dTable.Rows.Remove(dtRow)
        Next
        Return dTable

    End Function
```

what should i do?

thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide sample input and output, which illustrates what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: please have a look again, sorry again, i dont know how properly deal with the provided text editor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that illustrates the approach:

```
Dim dict As New dictionary(Of String, DataRow)

For Each dtRow As DataRow In dTable.Rows
  Dim key As String = dtRow("column1") + "," + dtRow("column2") ' + etc.
  Dim dictRow As DataRow = Nothing
  If dict.TryGetValue(key, dictRow) Then
    'check and update date
    'you can skip this part, if your data is sorted
    If dtRow("dateColumn") > dictRow("dateColumn") Then
      dictRow("dateColumn") = dtRow("dateColumn")
    End If
  Else
    dict.Add(key, dtRow)
  End If
Next
```

In the end `dict` contains the rows you need, you can get them via `dict.Values.ToArray()`

**EDIT:** I found the error - `dictRow` should be `dtRow` in the above code (now fixed). Then it should work. Here is a full version of self contained example (console app), since I wrote it anyway - focus on `RemoveDuplicates`, the rest is just prepwork:

```
Sub Main()
  Dim dt As New DataTable
  With dt.Columns
    .Add("PublishingPoint")
    .Add("Username")
    .Add("IP")
    .Add("Status")
    .Add("Req URL")
    .Add("Last seen", GetType(Date))
  End With

  'this populates the initial data table, use your method
  Dim _assembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
  Dim _textStreamReader As New StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApplication16.data.csv"))
  While Not _textStreamReader.EndOfStream
    Dim sLine As String = _textStreamReader.ReadLine().TrimEnd
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine) Then Exit While

    Dim values() As String = sLine.Split(",")
    Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    For iColumnIndex As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
      Dim columnName As String = dt.Columns(iColumnIndex).ColumnName
      newRow.Item(columnName) = values(iColumnIndex)
    Next
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
  End While

  Console.WriteLine("Old count: " & dt.Rows.Count)
  Dim newDt As DataTable = RemoveDuplicates(dt, "Last seen")
  Console.WriteLine("New count: " & newDt.Rows.Count)

  Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Function RemoveDuplicates(dt As DataTable, colName As String) As DataTable
  Dim keyColumnNames As New List(Of String)
  Dim exceptColumnsHash As New HashSet(Of String)({colName})
  For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
    Dim columnName As String = col.ColumnName
    If Not exceptColumnsHash.Contains(col.ColumnName) Then
      keyColumnNames.Add(columnName)
    End If
  Next

  Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, DataRow)
  For Each dtRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim keyColumnValues As New List(Of String)
    For Each keyColumnName In keyColumnNames
      keyColumnValues.Add(dtRow.Item(keyColumnName))
    Next
    Dim key As String = String.Join(",", keyColumnValues)

    Dim dictRow As DataRow = Nothing
    If dict.TryGetValue(key, dictRow) Then
      If dtRow(colName) > dictRow(colName) Then
        dictRow(colName) = dtRow(colName)
      End If
    Else
      dict.Add(key, dtRow)
    End If
  Next

  Dim dtReturn As DataTable = dt.Clone
  For Each dtRow As DataRow In dict.Values
    dtReturn.ImportRow(dtRow)
  Next
  Return dtReturn
End Function
```

To make this code run, you need to manually add a file to the project and set build action to "Embedded resource".

Comment: tank you so much for your efforts,appreciate it bro.i see 2 errors now one at this line `Dim exceptColumnsHash As New HashSet(Of String)({colName})` says **expression expected** and a green underline under **{** that i couldn't fix it due to my lack of intelligence! and another at this line which i managed to fix it by adding a **.toarray** :  `Dim key As String = String.Join(",", keyColumnValues.ToArray)` by editing dictrow in your previous code it's know works but not quiet complete! plz see befor(http://i62.tinypic.com/v3opw9.jpg) and then after (http://i59.tinypic.com/200a42r.jpg)

Comment: sorry last comment was full ! again i'm really grateful of your time and support, its very kind of you,i'll never forget, i've learned alot  ;)

Comment: @Arash: I forgot you are using VS2008. There is no hashset prior to .NET 4.0, which appears in VS2010. You can use a `List(of String)` instead, it's slightly slower, but same syntax (`Contains`). Also VS2008 is using VB syntax version 9, which does not support `{colName}`, you need to write `New String() {colName}` instead. Any other issues - let me know.

Comment: work like a charm! you don't know how grateful i am when all i can say is thank you! hope you success in your life, ;)